# Do you have an example where the third parameter is necessary for array_search to work properly in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

```
mixed array_search  ( mixed $needle  , array $haystack  [, bool $strict  ] )

If the third parameter strict  is set to TRUE  then the array_search() function will also check the types of the needle  in the haystack .
```

I don't see what it means,maybe an example can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the last argument is true, it will use [strict (also known as identity) comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) (`===`) when searching the array.

The equality comparison (`==`) compares the value where as the identity comparison (`===`) compares the value and the type.

```
'0' == 0 ; //true, the string is converted to an integer and then the are compared.
'0' === 0; //false, a string is not equal to a integer
```

You will find more information in this question [How do the equality (== double equals) and identity (=== triple equals) comparison operators differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-equality-and-identity-comparison-operators-differ)

This means that if you had an array of numbers

```
$a = array(0,1,2,3,4);
```

Using a strict comparison for the string value `'2'` will return false (not find a match) as there are no strings with the value `'2'`.

```
array_search('2', $a, true); //returns false
```

However if you don't do a strict search, the string is implicitly converted into an integer (or the other way around) and it returns the index of `2`, as `2 == '2'`

```
array_search('2', $a, false); //returns 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The third parameter tells the function to check also the **types** of needle and the haystack elements (i.e. to use a strict comparison `===`).

```
<?php

$needle = "2"; //a string
$haystack = array (1,2,"2","test");

$search = array_search  ($needle  ,$haystack,  false);

// Will output 1, as it is the key for the second element of the array (an integer)
print_r($search);


$search = array_search  ($needle  ,$haystack,  true);

//Will output 2, as it is the key for the third element of the array (a string)
print_r($search);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In array_search third argument is used for strict type checking.

For example if third argument is false ,  123 is equal to "123" ==> true

if third argument is true  , 123 is not equal to "123"  ==>  since both had different types  .